# Bootstrap 4 horizontal scrolling

Tags: php, html, css

I cannot get this one sorted:

I want my "Factuur" dutch for invoice always at 800px, but at the mobile view it shrinks the rows into each other, I want my invoice to be static and "scrollable". Here is my code (CSS):

```
    .invoice-box {
    max-width: 801px;
    min-width: 800px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
}
```

Normal view:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP7e7.jpg)

Mobile view:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WXyr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it

width: 800px;
overflow-x: scroll

Ps. Sorry mobile stack overflow have not formatting